# Entity Framework "Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes"

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an application built with `asp.net-core 2.0`.

I used `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` to integrate MySql.

The configuration which I use in Startup.cs is:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql("Server=localhost;port=3306;database=MyDB;user=MyDb_user;password=test123");
    ...
}
```

The `DbContext` for `ApplicationUser` which comes with the framework looks like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Now in MySql I created MyDB with Collation "utf8_general_ci".

But on DB migrate I am getting the error:

```
'Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes'
```

All solutions which I found to get this working with utf8 doesn't work with `asp.net-core 2.0`

Is there any solution for this with `asp.net-core 2.0`

Comment: Turn unicode off for Email and Username

Comment: Check these answers out, may be they will help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489041/mysqlerror-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109903/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
migrationBuilder.Sql("SET default_storage_engine=INNODB");
}
```

[Ability to specify engine, charset, ROW_FORMAT and more](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/84#issuecomment-473794411)